# How to find the curvature of a noisy function with few evaluations?

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, noise

I'm working on a project in computational solid state physics where I have to find the curvature of a smooth function $f \ : [0,\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ around the minimum point $x_0 = 0$.
The curvature is defined here as the second-order coefficient $a$ in the Taylor expansion $f(x) \approx f(0) + \frac{1}{2} a x^2$.

I can generate data points by evaluating the function at any point desired, but evaluations are expensive, so I would like to make as few evaluations as possible. Also, the function is subject to noise which can be assumed to be approximately Gaussian with mean $0$ and (known) variance $\sigma^2$. The problem is to determine what are the best points $x_i$ in which to sample the function in order to estimate $a$.

I have made some attempts to solve this issue, but I don't know how to go about finding an optimal solution. The main issue is that one wants to sample far from $x=0$ in order to minimize the effect of the noise, but close to $x=0$ in order to make sure that the function is still approximately parabolic.

As an example, consider the function $f(x) = \sin(\pi x) (e^x-1)$ shown in the figure below. This function has curvature $a = 2\pi$.
I've let the noise be Gaussian with standard deviation $\sigma = 0.05$, and sampled the noisy function at 10 evenly distributed points between $0$ and $1$ as shown in the figure.

[image]

So far I have tried to estimate the curvature by making a series of least-squares fits, where the first fit included only the first sample point, the next included the first two, and so on. These fits are shown below,

[image]

Here it is clear that some fits include too many sample points, and fail because they sample the function in regions where it is clearly no longer parabolic, while others fail because they include too few and are therefore too affected by the noise. From this small study, it seems that including the first 4-5 of the sample points yields the closest value for $a$. But this is all very *ad hoc*, and ideally I would like a suggestion for a more systematic way to approach the problem.

Edit: I should add that the noise is in fact somewhat deterministic, in the sense that sampling the same point $f(x_i)$ multiple times will always result in the same function value

Comment: Try taking the natural log (+1) of the data and then running OLS. Adding polynomial terms up to degree six should incrementally return better and better results.

Comment: On the contrary, adding polynomial terms is guaranteed eventually to produce ridiculous results.  This is the kind of problem addressed in the experimental design literature.  If you don't know $x_0$ this is addressed by *response surface* methods.  If you do know $x_0$ then some form of adaptive design would be promising.  A great deal depends on what you know and what you're willing to assume, as well as the trade-off you're willing to make between the cost of making an observation and the cost of an imprecise estimate.

Comment: Thank you that sounds quite interesting. Are there any resources you can recommend for an accessible introduction to response surface methods? In general for my problem I do not know $x_0$.

Comment: Actually there is a huge literature in support of using polynomials for curve fitting. Plug *fitting polynomials to data* into a search engine for confirmation. As a general rule, it's much less *ridiculous* to recommend simple approaches than the most sophisticated models to hapless OPs.

Comment: A standard text is https://www.amazon.com/Design-Analysis-Experiments-Douglas-Montgomery/dp/1118146921.  Beware the mischaracterization of your problem as mere "curve fitting:" I take you at your word that your project is important and the evaluations are expensive.  Those features, along with your objective of estimating the curvature at $x_0,$ clearly distinguish this situation from merely finding a function to approximate the data.  Indeed, you don't even need to find such a function: you only have to identify the region near the minimum *reliably* and estimate the curvature *locally.*

Comment: @huber Not a *mischaracterization* on my part but a misrepresentation on yours? A second *general rule* in data analysis is to start with the simplest models, e.g., OLS linear and/or curve-fitting polynomials, and then build up in complexity and sophistication. As the models evolve, changes in descriptive, inferential and predictive power emerge enabling decisions wrt comparative evaluation of costs and trade-offs.